# Origin of the surname Bargfleth

Tags: person-names, northern-german

What do *Barg* and *Fleth* mean when put together? This is a family name of mine and I’m trying to trace it. There is a place called *Barg* in either northern Germany or southern Denmark and *Fleth* I’m a little more vague on.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleet

Comment: For "Barg/Bjerg" i only found it as a district https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barg in Schleswig-Flensburg (in Schlewsig-Holstein/Germany)

Comment: Könnte _Fleth_ etwas mit Kanälen zu tun haben, wie in Hamburg, wo diese _Fleet_ heißen?

Comment: And there is the ship type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barge

Comment: @Martin Peters: Laut dem von mir verlinkten WP-Artikel ist die einheitliche Hamburger Schreibweise jung.

Answer (score 9):

This is one of the instances where English and northern German languages show their relation:

A **[fleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleet)** is a saline waterway, channel or inlet, literally meaning "something that flows" - the spelling varies a bit over time, but is recognizable. "Fleth" instead of "fleet" isn't far off. Especially 'h' often sort of a appears/disappears over time in many words. A few today examples are the "[Fleet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleet)" in Hamburg, the [river Fleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Fleet) in London and various villages in England that are located along marshy waterways by the same name.

Fleets sometimes were used for the transport of goods, a kind of natural equivalent to artificial channels. Especially in Hamburg, they are one of the important mehods of accessing the warehouses build along them and still a landmark today.

On these channels or fleets the typical vessel was a flat-bottomed boat, often without own engine, that was pulled or pushed along: A [barge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barge) or Barg (German).

And of course a number of ships are called a [fleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleet) again.

So Bargfleet could either be:

- a fleet (=multiples) of barges or
- a navigable waterway

Comment: These were some of the possibilities I had been mulling over in my mind.  I was just worried that there might have been something I was either overlooking or a nuance of the language I didn't know about.  Thank you all.